# In C++, can two other different shared objects access a Singleton from a third shared object?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, singleton, shared-libraries

I have an application in C++, which loads most of its code from two or more plugins (each with at least one thread), through share objects. I use the following code to load the plugins:

```
pluginHandle = dlopen(fileName, RTLD_NOW|RTLD_GLOBAL);
init_t* init = (init_t*) dlsym(pluginHandle, "init") // Create should return an instance of the class of the plugin
plugin = init();
```

I arrived to the point to which I need two of those plugins to start adding data to a common `Queue`. As the application does not allow for communication between both plugins without changing the code in the application itself (a point we are trying to avoid), I think I found a way to solve that: a third plugin, which includes a singleton class with a thread-safe `Queue`.

I would then recompile and link both plugins against the library, and use `getInstance()` to get the singleton and start adding tasks to the queue.

Is that a safe implementation? Will the singleton `Queue` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A dynamic library (shared object), which includes a singleton class with a thread-safe Queue.

Singleton are used when you want to constraint a class to be instantiated only once. That's **not** what you want: you want all your plugins to work on a particular instance of a class. There is no "only one can live" requirement here.

A thread-safe singleton in C++11 using Meyer's pattern may looks like this:

```
class Singleton
{
private:
    Singleton();

public:
    Singleton(const &Singleton) = delete;
    Singleton& operator=(const &Singleton) = delete;

    static Singleton& get_instance()
    {
         static Singleton s;
         return s;
    }
};
```

Default constructor is declared private, and copy/assignment operations are deleted to avoid multiple instances.

You need something more simple: a function always returning the same instance. Something like this:

```
class Manager
{
public:
    static Resource& get_resource()
    {
         static Resource r;
         return r;
    }
};
```

No need to prevent multiple instantiation: if you want the same instance, just ask for the same instance.

You can also extend the design with a resource pool returning a same instance given some id:

```
enum class ResourceId
{
    ID_FOR_A_FAMILY_OF_PLUGIN,
    ID_FOR_AN_OTHER_FAMILY_OF_PLUGIN
};

class Pool
{
public:
    static Resource& get_resource(ResourceId id)
    {
         static std::map<ResourceId, Resource> p;
         return p[id];
    }
};
```

Note that in this example `p[id]` is created on the fly with `Resource`'s default constructor. You may want to pass parameters during construction:

```
class Resource
{
public:
    Resource():ready(false){}

    void init(some parameters)
    {
        // do some intialization
        ready = true;
    }

    bool is_ready() const { return ready; }

private:
    bool ready;
};

class Pool
{
public:
    static Resource& get_resource(ResourceId id)
    {
         static std::map<ResourceId, Resource> p;
         auto& r = p[id];
         if(!r.is_ready())
         {
             r.init(some parameters);
         }
         return r;
    }
};
```

Or, using pointers to allow polymorphism:

```
class Pool
{
public:
    static std::unique_ptr<Resource>& get_resource(ResourceId id)
    {
         static std::map<ResourceId, std::unique_ptr<Resource>> p;
         auto& r = p[id];
         if(!r)
         {
             r = std::make_unique<SomeResourceTypeForId>(some parameters);
         }
         return r;
    }
};
```

Note that the last two implementations need a mutex around the non-static code to be thread-safe.